# Not able to find undeleted contact

Tags: undelete

I have deleted a contact record by mistake in salesforce. I found the record in Recycle Bin and undeleted it. I'm not able to find the record in salesforce. How much time does it usually take to get restored?

Comment: its immediate but the search may take a while. If you have the ID, modify the URL using the ID to go directly to the record. Or open the account and view it there

Comment: Tried both. Missing in both places.

Comment: Please check the List View Filter, if you are trying to see from List View.

Comment: Checked on workbench. Shows as deleted but does not allow undelete as it cannot be found in Recycle Bin

Answer (score 0):

You will be able to export the data using workbench. Select the checkbox to include deleted and archived contacts and then export the data which you need and finally you may import them back into your instance.